# Conditional class used in a make_shared with same parameters

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, make-shared

Consider this piece of code creating, based on a condition, a different class instance through a `std::make_shared`. Note that the two possible classes used (`Child1` and `Child2`) are having the same construction parameters.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base( int param )
    {
    }
};

class Child1 : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

class Child2 : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

std::shared_ptr<Base> getPtr( bool cond, int param )
{
    if ( cond )
        return std::make_shared<Child1>(param);
    else
        return std::make_shared<Child2>(param);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bool permissive = ...;
    Test::getPtr( permissive, argc );
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `permissive` is unknown at compilation time.

Is there a way to factorize argument list management in `getPtr` function with something like:

```
return std::make_shared<cond?Child1:Child2>(param);
```

This obviously does not compile but I could not find a way to make something similar work even using templates...

Comment: No, you can't. You have to use `if` or `switch` and specify a different class in each branch. If you have many of them, you can write a factory that maps `cond` to a function that creates the object, but this just moves the problem around.

Comment: If `cond `is known only at runtime there is nothing to be done. If it is known at compile time it can be made with `std::conditional` for example

Comment: @bartop, it's known at runtime

Comment: @j6t: Finally found a way to share the code handling parameters, see my answer.

Comment: `(cond ? +[](int i) -> std::shared_ptr<Base> { return std::make_shared<Child1>(i);} : +[](int i) -> std::shared_ptr<Base> { return std::make_shared<Child2>(i);})(3);` would indeed avoid to repeat argument, but it seems worst than your simple `if`

Comment: @Jarod42: It's not that bad. In my MCVE there's only one parameter, but I'm trying to find a solution because in my real code there are many of them!

Answer (score 2):

Best solution I could find to avoid duplicating code managing parameters is

```
class Helper
{
public:
    int param;

    template<class T> 
    std::shared_ptr<Base> create( int param )
    {
        return std::make_shared<T>(param);
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<Base> getPtr( bool cond, int param )
{
    Helper helper{param};
    return cond ? helper.create<Child1>() : helper.create<Child2>();
}
```

Comment: this solution bypasses the requriement of passing parameters to the constructor. What I mean is, if thats a viable solution you could as well provide default contructors and call them instead of the helper

Comment: It does need to pass a parameter. It's always 3 in my MCVE example, but it cannot be a default parameter, I'll update the posts to show this.

Answer (score 2):

With tuple, you might have only one parameter, so, something like:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Base> getPtr(bool cond, /*lot_of_params*/)
{
    std::tuple t{lot_of_params};

    if (cond)
        return std::apply([](auto&&... args){return std::make_shared<Child1>(args...);}, t);
    else
        return std::apply([](auto&&... args){return std::make_shared<Child2>(args...);}, t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is generalized solution i came up with while figuring similar problem. Works with several classes and several forwarded arguments. Uses indexing instead of branching. Does not suffer from code duplication.

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, typename... Args> 
::std::shared_ptr<Base> Impl(Args &&... args)
{
    return ::std::make_shared<T>(::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename... T, typename... Args>
::std::shared_ptr<Base> Make(::std::size_t const index, Args &&... args)
{
    return ::std::array{Impl<T, Args...>...}[index](::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
...
int main()
{
    auto cond{true};
    auto p_base{Make<Child1, Child2>(cond, 42)};
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:38,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:38,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aclass+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Base(int)%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Child1:+public+Base%0A%7B%0A++++public:+using+Base::Base%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Child2:+public+Base%0A%7B%0A++++public:+using+Base::Base%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T,+typename...+Args%3E+%0Astd::shared_ptr%3CBase%3E+Impl(Args+%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++return+std::make_shared%3CT%3E(::std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+T,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astd::shared_ptr%3CBase%3E+Make(::std::size_t+const+index,+Args+%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++return+::std::array%7BImpl%3CT,+Args...%3E...%7D%5Bindex%5D(::std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+cond%7Btrue%7D%3B%0A++++auto+p_base%7BMake%3CChild1,+Child2%3E(cond,+42)%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:59.7854526425955,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic+-Werror%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:40.2145473574045,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)